# How can I see the contents off a cfg file?

Tags: extension

I have some questions about the `.cfg` file format.

How can I open it and how can I edit the file so that it is still usable?

If I search on the internet for a `.cfg` file editor I didn't find anything usable.
I tried to edit it in `Notepad` or `Wordpad` it becomes unusable and if I use `Free File Viewer` I only can read it, but not editing.

Does anyone knows a good editor, so that the file is still usable after editing?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a question for another forum than Serverfault, but simply put:
.cfg is not a single well-defined file format, though you can usually assume it's a plaintext configuration file with human-readable contents.

From your question I assume it's a file for a Windows-based software. In that case Notepad is the easiest built-in way not to introduce problems. Just remember the following:

1. Notepad by default adds a .txt extension to file names. You need to `Save as...` and switch the `Save as type` field to `All files (*.*)`in the save dialog before storing the file with a `.cfg` suffix.
2. Windows by default hides file suffixes, so unless you take the previous step, files will look as though they have a `.cfg` suffix in the File Explorer/Computer view, but will in fact have a hidden `.txt` suffix and not be read by the software.

I suspect these two points explain why you couldn't get a (presumably correctly formatted) config file to work with your program.

Once you've outgrown Notepad, there's a bunch of editors to choose from:

- Notepad++ (as mentioned by @Norbert Weuster) is a nice pretty lightweight tool.
- Many programmers like to use the Sublime text editor, which can be used in a free mode but becomes a lot more powerful if you pay for it.
- If you can live with Electron apps (as opposed to native ones), Visual Studio Code is a pretty decent-looking "free" text editor.

Comment: My cfg file comes from a ENVIROMUX-16D devices. Which is probably Windows based but I am not sure. I can open the file in Notepad and I see the configuration in plain text but with some strange characters and white space. I think my file is probably formatted with some strange charset. How can I see which charset is used?

Answer (score 0):

I like Notepad++ very much.

It might help you in converting and encoding charsets and linefeeds.

Comment: If I use Notepad++ I get lots off `NUL` and `SOH` values in my file, but also some readable text, but lots off `NUL` values.

Comment: Then it is not a common ASCII editable config file and I would try to touch it unless there is an application specific editor or special tool.